# Какое предложение правильное?

Tags: склонение

Подскажите, какое предложение более правильно составлено? Имеют ли право на существования оба или какое-то из них ошибочно и несвободно? Может есть более простой и верный по смыслу вариант?
 В тексте говорится о сливах и даётся прилагательное "черносливовый,-ые". Вот эти предложения:
1.) "Произведённое из них вино, варенье называют, соответственно, черносливовым."
2.) "Из них делают вино и варят варенье, которые называют черносливовыми."
 Скажу сразу, смущает второй вариант окончанием -ыми, т.к. к нему напрашивается мн.ч. - "вина","варенья". Уместно ли обобщающее "черносливовыми"?
 Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

1. Произведённое из них вино или варенье называют, соответственно, черносливовым.
2. Из них делают вино и варят варенье, которое называют черносливовым.

Но если речь о сливах,почему вино или варенье черносливовое, а не сливовое? Чернослив-сушёная слива, а варенье ведь из живой сливы, не сушёной? И вино из сливы - сливовое, из чернослива - черносливовое.

Comment: Спасибо. А уместно ли слово "черносливовым" и для "вино" и для "варенье"? Каким правилом регулируется отношение прилагательного к обоим словам.
 P.S.: речь идёт о черносливе, но не как о сушеной сливе, а как о локальном названии (некоторых сортов) слив в обиходе.

Comment: 1.) "Произведённое из них вино, варенье называют, соответственно, черносливовым." -в ед. числе, потому что прилагат. относится к одному из однородных чл., на это указывает причастие "произведённое", бессоюзное перечисление может относить прилагат. и к одному, и ко всем компонентам. Чтобы убрать проблему разночтения, я вставила союз ИЛИ 2.) "Из них делают вино и варят варенье, которые называют черносливовыми."- понять можно тоже двояко, допускаются оба варианта, но привычнее согласовывать придаточное с последним определяемым словом.Множ. ч. тоже возможно.